# How to locate GUI elements via property browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

A simple question but I cannot seem to find a comfortable way of doing so or the right way to ask Google:
The combo box on top of the Property Browser shows all GUI elements created with the GUI designer.

Is there an easy way to locate the GUI element selected in the property browser like "Highlight Element" or something similar?

And how would one remove an "orphan" element which is not accessible by the designer anymore (do not ask me how this happened)?

For now the only way seems to be deleting manually in MyForm.Designer.cs.

Comment: i didn't get your point. are you saying, the object is outside the form and it's not visible?

Comment: In the properties explorer. you can see the name of your active object. it's the header of the property object. then you can click it. and all your objects will be display. then just select the object outside (make sure you know it's name) then after you select it. just press `delete` on the keyboard.

Comment: That is the point, I can select it in the property browser but NOT in the designer. Selecting an object in the property browser and pressing delete does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2012 menues. go to View|Other Windows|Document Outline

[image]

It will giv you a treelist view of all your controls on a Form. You can delete be selecting them in the window - and press Delete

Comment: That is what I was looking for...Thanks! But nevertheless my object is not listed there. So, I guess it is a bug. I was having an issue with some designer inconsistency recently. Might be a result of that.

Comment: With the WinForms designer you never know.. 
If your object is not listed here perhaps it has not been added til the forms control collection `Controls`. Try deleting it manualy from the form.designer.cs file.